# How to debug a Flutter app in Edge browser by attaching browser?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, browser, vscode-debugger

I am developing a Flutter app, however I want to debug the app using the Edge browser where I have an extension installed to visualize how my app would look like on an IOS device, but when the app starts debugging it opens a completely different instance browser than the one I have installed and I don't have access to use the extensions.

I tried to solve the problem by attaching the browser when debugging using the following steps:

1. Configuring my launch.json

[image]

2. Executing the command: start msedge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

[image]

And it opens a common browser window where I go to the url that specified in the launch.json

[image]

3. Lastly I start debbugging the app using Attach to Edge

[image]

But I got the following error
[image]

I´ve also tried putting the url "http://localhost:9222" but it does´t work
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `"deviceId": "edge"` to launch on edge directly

```json
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "so_nov22",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "edge"
        },
```

Or run on server use `flutter run -d web-server`

```json
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "so_nov22",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "deviceId": "web-server",
        },
```

last one will open the url on default browser

Comment: `flutter run -d edge`

Comment: `-d` is used to select device here device is `edge`