# VSCode: Debug/Run a Flutter installed on a remote server but visualize it on a local browser

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to make VSCode to use a specific local browser (in my case Microsoft Edge) for a Flutter app installed remotely ?

I have tried to create this launch.json:

```
{
    // launch.json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Flutter for web",
        "type": "dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "lib/main.dart",
        "args": [
          "-d",
          "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I still get:

```
No supported devices found with name or id matching 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'.
```

Thanks

Comment: can you not use `"deviceId": "edge"`? see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74226893/11107541